# Hitting tablix exception with rdlc

Tags: visual-studio-2013, rdlc, ssrs-tablix, report-designer

I try to add new rows to my rdlc report using Microsoft Visual Studio 2010. When I try to generate the report I am hitting this exception.

Exception:

***Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ReportPublishingException: The tablix 'table12' has an incorrect number of TablixRows. The number of TablixRows must equal the number of innermost TablixMembers (TablixMembers with no submembers) in the TablixRowHierarchy.***

Really appreciate if someone could help me out.

Answer (score 3):

Too late for you but maybe this will help someone else. I got this error when I removed a TablixRow node from my Tablix node within the underlying XML. Apparently there needs to be a matching number of TablixMember nodes within the TablixRowHierarchy node and by removing it, they no longer matched. Removing the extra TablixMember node solved the problem.

Pretty much what the error message says but I didn't understand it until I figured it out (all too common a tale).

```
<Tablix>   
    <TablixBody>
        <TablixRows>
            <TablixRow></TablixRow>
            <!--<TablixRow></TablixRow> Initially only removed this -->
        </TablixRows>
    </TablixBody>     
    <TablixRowHierarchy>
        <TablixMembers>
            <TablixMember></TablixMember>
            <!--<TablixMember></TablixMember> Had to remove this one to fix -->
        </TablixMembers>
    </TablixRowHierarchy>
</Tablix>
```